# Fire change event in custom angular form component

Tags: angular, data-binding, event-handling

With the help of some tutorials I implemented a custom Angular2 Component, that uses two range inputs to achieve a dual range slider

Everything is working fine except the binding of the two values to the form Element.

Because I use these component multiple times in one form I need to acces the event target of the change event. Unfortunately the change event is still bound to the inputs my component depents on.

I made some MWE on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/controlvalueaccessorgeneric-c3vzq8

Comment: Why do you want to send the target to your parent component? If your component is a form input, shouldn't you just update the form value it is in?

Comment: I'm new to angular and do not really know how to achieve the bidning between the slider and the form

Comment: You're on the right track using the ControlValueAccessor. I'm looking at your stackblitz. I'll write an answer if I have time. I was wondering if it is normal the sliders can cross, making the selected range being the one outside the two sliders.

Comment: Hei @PaulEvans, thanks a lot. This is what I wanted to achieve because the dual Slider should handle harvest seasons in the year. And those can cross new years eve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/controlvalueaccessorgeneric-bt458y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdual-slider-component%2Fdual-slider-component.component.ts).

This is not very close to what your original code looks like, but I tried making it as simple as possible, using the ControlValueAccessor.

The trick here is to use a for in your slider component, which is in charge of the values, which are then passed to the parent component/form.

There is no need for you to know which slider moved!

I do not have a lot of time tonight, but if you have any questions, don't hesitate to tag me. I'll be happy to help you understand this as it is not the most trivial thing.

Comment: you are incredible. I just had a quick overview but that helps me so much. I will go over the solution tomorrow to exactly understand what you did. Apprechiate your work so much. Regards Manuel

Comment: @manuel Also, there's probably a way to combine `onSlideOne` and `onSlideTwo` into one function (I haven't read in depth what it actualy does, if you can explain it I might have time to help you). This would be an even prettier solution where you won't have two subscriptions, but only one on `this.subForm.valueChanges.subscribe( v => func(v));`

Comment: well ok, I had a few minutes to compare your solution with my basic approach. The main difference seams to be: you're nesting the inputs of the dual slider in another formGroup. Is that the main way to go if one want to implement some custom form Components ?

Comment: @manuel It's one way to do it. I imagine there are a lot of solutions, but this is the one I use a lot since the formGroup takes in charge the valalueChanges, validation and many other. This allows you to build something very modular.